# Why do I get a "missing comma" error?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written an SQL code. But there is some "missing comma" error. How do I fix that?

```
insert into mark ("value number", student_id, subject_id) values(100,1,1);
insert into mark ("value number", student_id, subject_id) values(90,2,1);


SQL ERROR: 
insert into mark (value number, student_id, subject_id) values("100",1,1)
                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00917: missing comma
```

Comment: The error message has double quotes around `100`, but the SQL does not. Is the SQL you posted the same as what produced the error?

Comment: Pretty sure you don't want quotes around value number

Comment: Additionally, the error doesn't have quotes around `value number`, which would explain the error.

Comment: Am using oracle software

Comment: Allans 2nd comment confirms once again the doubt whether the sql is the one that produced the error. And is the column really named "value number"?

Comment: [value number] perhaps?

Comment: I'm able to insert the values correctly. Check out the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ee9ff)

Comment: @Schuere [ ] is for microsoft products

Comment: @TilmanHausherr; my bad, it came to mind

Comment: @user5268891 if you can, then just change that column name to value_number or value_id. You've then likely gotten rid of the problem. If you don't want to change it, then edit your question to mention whether you're calling from the command line or from a programming language.

Comment: Are u sure that this is the exact SQL u r using to insert the data.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't like the quotes around the column named "value number". It is inadvisable to have a column with a space in it unless necessary. Could you change this column to be value_number and then remove the quotes from your query?

Alternatively you needn't list the column names at all so long as you list values for every column and list them in the order they appear in the table. If you have values for every column in the right order you can completely remove `("value number", student_id, subject_id)` from your query.

Comment: insert into mark values(100,1,1);
insert into mark values(90,2,1);   The error is integrity contraint violated- parent key not found.

Comment: then one of your columns is marked as a foreign key and the value you are trying to assign to it isn't allowed. [link] (http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_02291_integrity_constraint_string_string_violated_parent_key_not_found.htm)

Comment: @user5268891 your question is evolving into a moving target. The best would be that you delete the question, and write a new one, but this time with the CREATE command(s) of all tables involved, and the select command, the error message of that select command, and the database name. If you can, don't use names with a space in it.